# htaccess removing extension in two different pages

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i used the htacess to remove the php extension and it worked but i also have a page called profile wich i shorten but that make the pages names being taken as a a profile user name, is there a way to fix this?

the results i want is like this:

`localhost/path_folder/index.php` to `localhost/path_folder/index`

and

`localhost/path_folder/profile?username=name` to `localhost/path_folder/name`

and my `htaccess` code for the removing extension is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

and the code for the profile page is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path_folder/profile.php?username=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

## First try To internally redirect /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /path_folder/$1.php [L]

## if PHP file not found then load profile page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /path_folder/profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove file extension

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^path_folder/([^/]*)$ path_folder/$1.php [L]
```

Shorten URL for userprofiles

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^path_folder/profile/([^/]*)$ path_folder/profile?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: the problem is that the htaccess takes the page name as the profile username

Comment: Yes, it does. 
You want something like that? path_folder/profile/username

Comment: yeah i thought of that but is there a way that the path profile don't show in the url?

Comment: Then just put **/profile** between _path_folder_ and **/([^/]*)$**

Comment: Changed my answer now